# CS50 AI: Tic Tac Toe. Player X has 3 in a row, yet doesn't win, O picks next a 3rd one and wins

Tags: python, cs50, tic-tac-toe

I'm finishing AI50's tic tac toe, everything seems to be working, including the minimax algorithm but I came across a play (which almost always repeats itself), when the following steps occur as I am the X player:

[2][2] : X

[0][0] : O

[0][2] : X

[2][0] : O

At this point i place the final X between the previous two at [1][2], yet I don't win, the game goes on and O places it's third at [1][0] and wins the game. If I'm playing as player O, similar can happen when the AI doesnt place it's 3rd winning mark in the middle but puts it between my 2 to block me from winning.

Is the problem with my Minimax function or the winner function fails to detect ?

Apart from this I have won other games and the AI can win too in other scenarios, everything seems to be fine.

Here is my code:

```
"""
Tic Tac Toe Player
"""

import math
from random import randint
from copy import deepcopy

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    x_count = 0
    o_count = 0
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == X:
                x_count += 1
            if board[i][j] == O:
                o_count += 1

    if x_count == o_count:
        return X
    else:
        return O


def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    possible_actions = set()
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] == EMPTY:
                possible_actions.add((i, j))
    return possible_actions


def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    copied_board = deepcopy(board)
    if copied_board[action[0]][action[1]] == EMPTY:
        copied_board[action[0]][action[1]] = player(board)
    else:
        raise Exception("Not a valid move")
    return copied_board


def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """ 
    # Check horizontally and vertically
    for i in range(3):
            if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2]:
                return board[i][0]

            elif board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i]:
                return board[0][i]

    # Check diagonally
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        return board[0][0]

    elif board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2]:
        return board[2][0]
        
    # Return None if tie, as in none of the above conditions were met
    else:
        return None
        

def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X or winner(board) == O or (winner(board) == None and len(actions(board)) == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    if winner(board) == X:
        return 1
    elif winner(board) == O:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal move for the current player on the board.
    """
    # Check for terminal state
    if terminal(board):
        return None

    # If X's turn
    elif player(board) == X:
        options = []
        for action in actions(board):
            score = min_value(result(board, action))
            # Store options in list
            options.append([score, action])
        # Return highest value action
        return sorted(options, reverse=True)[0][1]

    # If O's turn
    else:
        options = []
        for action in actions(board):
            score = max_value(result(board, action))
            # Store options in list
            options.append([score, action])
        # Return lowest value action
        return sorted(options)[0][1]


def max_value(board):
    """
    Returns the highest value option of a min-value result
    """
    # Check for terminal state
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)

    # Loop through possible steps
    v = -math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        v = max(v, min_value(result(board, action)))
    return v


def min_value(board):
    """
    Returns the smallest value option of a max-value result
    """
    # Check for terminal state
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)
    
    # Loop through possible steps
    v = math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        v = min(v, max_value(result(board, action)))
    return v
```

Comment: The `winner()` function looks fine to me, so the problem must be with the other logic. Try stepping through the code with a debugger, or add print statements to see what's happening. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `winner` function: it returns `None` when it finds a three-in-a-row of `None` values. This in itself may seem OK, but thereby it may miss a real three-in-a-row of X or O. This wrong assessment happens in the deeper state that arises from the board you described:

```
O . X
. . X
O . X
```

Now `winner` will never look at the third column, because it already exits when it looks at the second column... with `None`.

There are different ways to correct this:

- Extend the `if` conditions like this:

  ```
      if board[i][0] and board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2]:
  #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          return board[i][0]
  ```

  ... and add a similar extra condition in all the other `if` statements there.

  OR:
- Initialise the board with all distinct values, and then you need to alter the conditions where you use `== EMTPY` and instead use `not in (X, O)`

Comment: Oh I see now! Thank you very much. Will change it tomorrow. Am i understanding correctly that the""" if board[i][0] and""" part works because if its empty/ None it will return False therefore will only work if its X or O?

Answer (score -2):

I believe your if conditions within the winner function need to be tweaked.

This is your current code.

```
def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """ 
    # Check horizontally and vertically
    for i in range(3):
            if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2]:
                return board[i][0]

            elif board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i]:
                return board[0][i]

    # Check diagonally
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        return board[0][0]

    elif board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2]:
        return board[2][0]
        
    # Return None if tie, as in none of the above conditions were met
    else:
        return None
```

Usually, when defining multiple test conditions one uses the "and" or "or" conjunction as follows.

```
def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """ 
    # Check horizontally and vertically
    for i in range(3):
            if board[i][0] == board[i][1] and board[i][1] == board[i][2]:
                return board[i][0]

            elif board[0][i] == board[1][i] and board[1][i] == board[2][i]:
                return board[0][i]

    # Check diagonally
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        return board[0][0]

    elif board[2][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[0][2]:
        return board[2][0]
        
    # Return None if tie, as in none of the above conditions were met
    else:
        return None
```

See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Python allows condition chaining. `x == y == z` is perfectly valid, it's equivalent to `x == y and y == z`